# All listbox items colored instead of one by one

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

When my listbox's `DrawItem` event is fired. I would like to iterate through its items and if each item's text meets a certain condition, then their background color will be green and if not, they will be yellow.

With the following code, I get all my items with the same color. I am not very good at programming graphics in `C Sharp` I guess.

```
private void listBoxYourSelection_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    ListBox lst = (ListBox)sender;

    foreach(string item in lst.Items)
    {                
        Color col = new Color();
        e.DrawBackground();
        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
        if (CONDITIONISTRUE)
            col = Color.Green;
        else
            col = Color.Yellow;
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(col), e.Bounds);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(col), e.Bounds);
        if (e.Index >= 0)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(lst.Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My guess is that your "CONDITIONISTRUE" is always either true or false

Comment: Without knowing what `CONDITIONISTRUE` is its impossible to help, it doesn't seem to ever be set anywhere and if it is an implementation detail then you would need to share that too

Comment: @Vajura I just did a check and I realized the condition is sometimes false and true. But I think the fact that I am iterating through my `listbox` every time an item is added is confusing the method. So my question is, instead of `ListBox lst = (ListBox)sender;` how can I only capture the item that has been added?

Comment: @Pedram this is actualy the most "safe" way of doing this, my guess still is your "CONDITIONISTRUE" is not correct. Use a random function in that if and see if stuff changes because it should

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake is indeed to iterate over the Items in the `ListBox`.

You don't need to care about any other `Item` since the `DrawItem` method is doing that already for you! It will be called separately for each Item in your ListBox, whenever the system thinks it is necessary..

All you need to take care of is choosing the right `Color, Font, Text` etc for the **one** `Item` you are painting in the current call.

You can identify which Item is being painted by looking at the `e.Index` parameter.

A slightly modified version could look like this:

```
private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
        // for testing I turn on every other item; 
        // you will want to use another way to decide..!!
        bool CONDITIONISTRUE = e.Index % 2 == 0;

        bool selected = listBox1.SelectedIndex == e.Index;

        Color col = new Color();
        if (CONDITIONISTRUE)
            col = selected ? SystemColors.HotTrack : Color.PaleGreen;
        else
            col = selected ? SystemColors.HotTrack : Color.Gold;

        e.DrawBackground();           // not really needed
        e.DrawFocusRectangle();       // not really needed either

        using (Pen pen = new Pen(col))
        using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(col))
        {
          e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(col), e.Bounds);
          e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(col), e.Bounds);
        }
        if (e.Index >= 0)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(listBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString(), 
                       e.Font, selected? Brushes.White:Brushes.Black, 
                       e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);            }
    }
}
```

Obviously the CONDITIONISTRUE should be set in some other way in you code! If it is a method you may want to include the item index as a parameter..

**Note 1:** Since your drawing fills each Item completely, the currently selected Item can't be recognized any longer. I solve this issue by choosing between more colors: Instead of the usual `SystemColors.HotTrack` with white text you could you could use any other colors you like, of course..or simply a bold font..

**Note 2:** Since ListBox tries to 'optimize' itself by not **always** drawing **every** Item we need to force it by adding this:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.Invalidate();
}
```